# Propel with Schema.xml

Tags: xml, yaml, propel, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to generate model in Propel using Schema.xml, instead of [Schema.yml](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/05-Configuring-Symfony)?

There was once upon a time when xml was used for database generation in Propel, but it had been dropped in favor of yml. I should go for yml if I were handcoding my database schema, but now since I directly export my database schema from MySQL workbench using [a plugin](http://www.diloc.de/blog/2008/08/05/mysql-workbench-propel-export-plugin-v04/), and the result is in xml format, I have no choice but to work with xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer: [Just put your schema.xml in the folder where schema.yml is located](http://www.librosweb.es/symfony_1_1_en/capitulo8/extended_schema_syntax.html) and run the command line

```
php symfony propel:build-model
```

and you will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using a yml file at all, because I don't use Symfony.
In the folder contining my build.properties file, I run:

```
propel-gen ./ creole
```

That connexts to my database, reverse engineers it, and generates my schema.xml
Then I just run:

```
propel-gen ./
```

That uses the schema.xml file to generate my models.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify @lo_fye's answer, Propel has always used XML. It's Symfony that offered a YAML option, and even then you could use XML if you wished. Assuming you're using Symfony, it is just a question of popping in a schema.xml file rather than a schema.yml file.

FWIW, although XML schemas are slightly less readable, I prefer them. It feels a bit more solid, perhaps because I find the space thing in YAML fiddly.

Edit: ah, the last answer was from the OP - apols. Glad you fixed it.